# Cassandra - search by primary key using an arbitrary subset of the primary key columns

Tags: nosql, cassandra

**Is it possible to find records in Cassandra who's primary key matches an arbitrary subset of all of the primary key fields?**

#### Example:

Using the table described below, it is possible to find the records whos's primary key has a particular `type` and `name` without specifying an `id` or `size`?

```
CREATE TABLE playlists (
  id      uuid,
  type    text,
  name    text,
  size    int,

  artist text,

  PRIMARY KEY (id, type, name, size)
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At least in Cassandra 1.2 it is possible but it is disabled by default,

If you try to make this:

```
SELECT * from playlist where type = 'sometype' and name = 'somename';
```

You will receive this error:

```
Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

Then you can enable it running this:

```
SELECT * from playlist where type = 'sometype' and name = 'somename' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

In your example Cassandra will allow you to do queries using a complete subset of the primary key from left to right, for example:

```
SELECT * from playlist where id = 'someid'; (ALLOWED)
SELECT * from playlist where id = 'someid' and type = 'sometype'; (ALLOWED)
SELECT * from playlist where id = 'someid' and type = 'sometype' and name = 'somename'; (ALLOWED)
SELECT * from playlist where id = 'someid' and type = 'sometype' and name = 'somename' and size=somesize; (ALLOWED)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah ok, so using an arbitrary subset that is not in order could result on performance that is not O(log n) time?

Comment: The id field in your example is the partition key, which determines the storage location of the rows. A filter using this key in your where clause enables Cassandra to efficiently redirect the query to the nodes that have the corresponding data. The absence of this partition key makes that Cassandra has to send your query to all nodes in the cluster, which is inefficient and therefore disabled by default. The 'ALLOW FILTERING' clause enables such searches, but you  should regard this as a hint that you may want to change your schema...