# Querying for empty string with cql 1.4.0 in Python 2.7

Tags: python, database, cassandra, cql, string

Trying to query a Cassandra 1.2 table for a column with empty strings, I am getting an error:

```
cql.apivalues.ProgrammingError: Bad Request: Key may not be empty
```

**Context:**

The CQL statement being sent uses a cursor and is intended to get all rows where the `first_name` column has an empty string.  The `cql_query` text sent to the cursor is:

```
SELECT obj_key 
     FROM person_first_name_last_name
     WHERE first_name = :first_name_0 AND last_name = :last_name_1
     LIMIT 50
```

with params:

```
{'first_name_0': '', 'last_name_1': 'd'}
```

As far as I understand, this should be possible.  However, this error seems to indicate that an empty string is not a valid search value.  What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't have a null column value when that column is the key or it is part of a composite key (at least not in CQL).

The workaround is to set the column to a non-existing value in your data, in your example using 'zx123' should be enough, since nobody has zx123 as a first name or last name. Using a simple blank (space) should work too of course.

Comment: Interesting.  So `''` counts as a null value for a column?

Comment: It counts as an empty value, which is the problem with Cassandra, it needs to match the full key to ensure a fast search on the data (or a left subgroup of the composite key as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575572/cassandra-search-by-primary-key-using-an-arbitrary-subset-of-the-primary-key-c/16575885#16575885)